# 403 on JSON PUT request to Tomcat with Spring 3.0.5 and Jackson

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-security, jackson

My web application has started returning 403 errors on PUT requests. However, I'm not seeing any debug messages in the logs for this request so I'm stumped as to how to debug this further.

This code used to work but there have been a number of recent changes:
Client is Sencha JS:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
        url       : '/RestWAR/personal/trailSegment/' + trailSegment.id + '.json',
        method    : 'PUT',
        headers   : {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        jsonData  : segmentDto
});
```

The container is Apache Tomcat 6.0. 
The request goes to Spring Security 3.0.0.RC1 before going to Spring 3.0.5.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/personal")
public class PersonalController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "trailSegment/{trailSegmentId}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public void updateTrailSegment(@PathVariable long trailSegmentId, @RequestBody PersonalTrailSegmentDTO trailSegmentDto) {
    //...
    }
}
```

Recent changes:
Spring was on 3.0.0.M4 and the json library was net.sf.json-lib 1.0.2.
Spring is now 3.0.5 and the json library is now Jackson Mapper ASL 1.4.2 (i.e. what Spring recommends).

GETs and POSTs are working fine. It's just PUTs that are failing.

If Spring Security were involved then I would be seeing debug messages from Spring Security but I see nothing at all. It appears that Tomcat is stopping the request.

Thanks in advance for any help - especially in regards to debugging this.

Comment: Why are you still using a beta version of Spring Security?

Comment: I'm interested to see if there's a solution to this, we hit the same thing with Tomcat 6.0.x and Spring 3.0.1 using PUT & @RequestParam (I think we tried @RequestBody too), PUTs were working fine with Jetty but not with Tomcat, unless you add the parameter to url as ?someParam=value. We chose to go around it just by using POST instead.

Comment: I'm using the beta version because I upgraded Spring last release and didn't want to but off too much more by upgrading Spring Security as well. When I reviewed the change log I didn't see anything that was concerning. I will certainly fix this as some stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was returning null from the `updateTrailSegment()` method. This causes Spring to attempt to map the request using `InternalResourceView` with a url of what's in the request - i.e. `/RestWAR/personal/trailSegment/1761`. The `InternalResourceView` means that it attempts to resolve that URL as a path within the application. As there is none - it fails.

The fix is to use as the return type:

```
@ResponseBody ExtResponse
```

ExtResponse is just a simple POJO to return a response code.

The full method is now:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "trailSegment/{trailSegmentId}", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
public @ResponseBody ExtResponse updateTrailSegment(@PathVariable long trailSegmentId, @RequestBody PersonalTrailSegmentDTO trailSegmentDto) {
    trailSegmentDto.setId(trailSegmentId);
    PersonalTrailSegment trailSegment = trailSegmentAssembler.assembleDomain(trailSegmentDto);
    trailSegmentDataGateway.update(trailSegment);
    return new ExtResponse("true", "");
}
```

Comment: Good to hear you got it working, have to try something like this sometime myself to see if it could solve our Tomcat-PUT-403 -problem (although everything is working just fine with POSTs now, so not that we actually need it anymore, but just out of curiosity)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm interested to see if there's a
>   solution to this, we hit the same
>   thing with Tomcat 6.0.x and Spring
>   3.0.1 using PUT & @RequestParam (I think we tried @RequestBody too), PUTs
>   were working fine with Jetty but not
>   with Tomcat, unless you add the
>   parameter to url as ?someParam=value.
>   We chose to go around it just by using
>   POST instead.

I just posted that as a comment a few minutes ago, now that I thought back when we hit this, I remembered I found [this](http://tomcat.markmail.org/message/blc2rhzafde7uwgr?q=Parameters%20disappear%20from%20PUTs#query%3aParameters%20disappear%20from%20PUTs%20page:1%20mid%3adxgvu6fhcvp22xbo%20state%3aresults) thread (*Parameters disappear from PUTs*) about the issue back then. Reading through it, it seems the Tomcat-developers interpreted the HTTP-specification to mean that PUT should not support parameters:

> Well, are you sure that a PUT request
>   actually admits "parameters" ?
>   http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt,
>   section 9.6
>
> A PUT request requests that the
>   attached entity (in the requst body)
>   be stored at the location indicated by
>   the URI. But I see no reference to
>   parameters here.

-

> There is anyway enough leeway in these
>   paragraphs, to justify the fact that
>   the Tomcat developers may have been
>   justified to not implement any
>   handling of "parameters" for PUT
>   requests; while developers of other
>   servlet engines may have felt
>   justified in providing such handling.
>   The point I am trying to make is that
>   if you create an application which
>   depends on parameters being processed
>   in a PUT request, you may well create
>   an application which is not portable
>   to all servlet engines or HTTP
>   servers. But that is of course your
>   choice.
>
> All this triggers a question however :
>   in an earlier post, you mention that
>   the request works fine as a POST. Why
>   then do you insist to send it as a PUT
>   ?

Comment: I'm doing a RESTful interface. POST means create a document. PUT means replace it. Your comment suggests that I need to make sure the document is sent back in the request body but I believe I've done that by using @RequestBody. Something to double check though.

Comment: I figured that. If you meant the 'All this triggers a question however : in an earlier post, you mention that the request works fine as a POST. Why then do you insist to send it as a PUT ?'-part, it's a sitation from the thread I linked to, and was meant at the OP of the thread.

Comment: I wanted to continue to use PUT, if at all possible, to keep the ideological cleanness of my interface. :-) More to the point, I wanted to understand why it was failing instead of blindly trying stuff.

Comment: Excellent response - the "link" aka http://markmail.org/thread/bqb44tqnhmvtlji6 is extremely useful albeit 37 messages in the thread!