# Spring with Tomcat 7: PUT request returns 403 for strange resons

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have a web application written on Spring 3.1 (not boot) and running on Tomcat 7.

I have a @Controller implements method PUT on a certain URL.
In some cases When sending a PUT request from Postman, I get a 403 response instead of what is expected.

For example:

1. Sending the request to a non-implemented URL (on GET to the same URL I get a 404)
2. Sending an invalid JSON as the request body (Expected 400)
3. Sending a string instead of a numeric request parameter (Expected 400)

I also implement a filter that excepts all requests and just before the filter exists, I can verify I get the expected status from the rest of the chain.

This is an example of a controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{book}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
protected Book put(@PathVariable(value = "bookId") String id, @RequestBody @Valid Book book) {
    return book;  // just a stub
}
```

And this is the relevant part in the filter:

```
filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
// res.getStatus() is the expected status
return; // after this line I move to internal code of Tomcat which I cannot debug, but something happens there.
```

What do I miss?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have CSRF protection enabled?

Comment: I don't know. For testing I'm using the maven tomcat plugin. How can I check it out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [403 on JSON PUT request to Tomcat with Spring 3.0.5 and Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5433434/5221149)

Comment: It can also be because of ' protected ' Keyword which it cannot able to access. Try changing to public

Comment: Andreas, this link deals with manager protection. This is not my case. Making the method public also didn't work.
This is strange since when passing a valid Book object in the body, it works. But when passing an invalid JSON in the body, I expect my validator to return 400, but Tomcat returns 403 instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check out CORS filter configuration first as Andreas said: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/filter.html
2. Check out this flowchart also https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/images/cors-flowchart.png
3. Check out this stackoverflow post finally [403 on JSON PUT request to Tomcat with Spring 3.0.5 and Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5433434/403-on-json-put-request-to-tomcat-with-spring-3-0-5-and-jackson)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It appears that none of this related to CORS. There is no Origin header. Also, PUT requests returns OK when the request body is a valid JSON. The problem begins when the input is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Your path variable value is *bookId*, but your url uses *{book}*; both should match. Try changing the url to *"/{bookId}"* or the path variable to *@PathVariable(value = "book")*. It might be useful to know the URL that you are calling to help analyse the issue.